# How do I emit to specific socket in Python flask socketio?

Tags: python, flask, websocket, flask-socketio

Is it possible to emit to a specitic client by socketId. It can either be from the backend(python) or frontend(js/jquery)?
This is what I want to do:

```
emit('my event', TO SPECIFIC SOCKET-ID)
```

or

```
socket.emit('my event', TO SPECIFIC SOCKET-ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

The front end can only emit to the server. The back end can emit to all clients, a subset of clients (using rooms) or to a single client.

To emit to one client from the server using Python:

```
emit('my event', to=sid)
```

Where `sid` is the identifier for the client you want to target. If instead you prefer to emit an event to a group of clients that were put in a room, you can do it with:

```
emit('my event', to=room)
```

Where `room` is the name of the room in question.